# interrupt one api call while multiple api calls are simultaneously running and give priority for the interrupted api call in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am sending multiple httpclient request simultaneously.If I am navigating to particular page.I have to send api call related to that page and response should come immediately for that api call.Can anyone pls help me.

Iam having a service method like below.I called this in my home page ,then Iam navigating to another page while its running.I should interrrupt another api call and should get get response immediately for that api call.

```js
MultipleApiMethod() {
  this.GetFirstDataFromApi().subscribe(res => { });
  this.GetFirstDataFromApi().subscribe(res => { });
}

GetFirstDataFromApi() {
  let url = "firstdataapi"
  return this._httpClient.get(url).map(res => res).catch(err => {
    return
    Observable.throw(err)
  });
}

GetSecondDataFromApi() {
  let url = "seconddataapi"
  return this._httpClient.get(url).map(res => res).catch(err => {
    return
    Observable.throw(err)
  });
}
```

.
.
.

Thanks

Comment: Some code would help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to achieve the following:

> When executing First Api request, then Second Api request, while the
>   first and second have reached the server, a Third Api request is being
>   made, and if it meets a certain condition it should return from server
>   to client before the First and Second Api requests.

This can't be achieved from client-side alone in a high-standard code.

You can add an Enum value of various states you need to the httpClient request so the server interprets this state as a condition for a WAIT mechanism (as in multithreaded await in C# for example).

This means you need to handle multiple threads.

A crooked way to do this from client-side alone would be to use a middleWear service like Authguard to handle all your requests, firstly adding a loader that hides the screen while requests have not returned, and setting a reasonable timeout until Third Api call have not returned in order to use a switch case to decide what should happen next depending the return responses.

good luck buddy

Comment: thanks for your response.But,I think,this is not related to my question.I don't want to give any restriction while route navigation.I need to interrupt one api call while multiple api calls are inprogress and should get response first.then I should get other api calls response.

Comment: Do you mean that for example: When executing First Api request, then Second Api request, while the first and second have reached the server, a Third Api request is being made, and if it meets a certain condition it should return from server to client before the First and Second Api requests?